# What should rotation vectors look like?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, vector

I instantiate cones along Grid mesh and add offset by noise texture.

I'm wondering what these rotation vectors look like. I can't figure out what they look like.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not a vector, it is regular Euler rotation angles. I believe that you are familiar with them:

[image]

Only difference, that they in radians, not in degrees. You can use them, for example, to rotate instances

For example, this setup rotates cones according to the face normals, and Align Euler to Vector is used to convert normal vector to rotation triple.

[image]

Comment: What does it mean to have Rotation socket unconnected in the Align Euler to Vector node? What is the default value which is being rotated by the node according to the face normal vector? What can you connect here except the output of another Align Euler to Vector node (which looks like cyclic)?